# Search & match data from database then show result

Tags: php, search, mysqli

```php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $desg=$_POST['desg'];
    $cities=$_POST['cities'];
    $exp=$_POST['exp'];
    $prof=$_POST['prof'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM adjob WHERE desg like '%".$desg."%' OR cities like '%".$cities."%' OR exp like '%".$exp."%' OR prof like '%".$prof."%'";
    $q=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
else
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM adjob";
    $q=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <table width="200" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Desgination</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="desg" value="" /></td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cities" value="" /></td>
            <td>Experince</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="exp" value="" /></td>
            <td>Profile</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="prof" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Desg</td>
        <td>Cities</td>
        <td>Exp</td>
        <td>Prof</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['desg']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['cities']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['exp']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['prof']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

I am using this code to search from the table. I have to the fill 4 fields to fetch the data of one row .. How can i fill two or three fields & match the columns from database & search data (the way we search in various job portals) ?? Thanks in advance _/_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your search pattern  according to user input as

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $desg = $_POST['desg'];
    $cities = $_POST['cities'];
    $exp = $_POST['exp'];
    $prof = $_POST['prof'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adjob WHERE ";
    $flag = FALSE;

    if (isset($desg) && $desg != "") {// condition for desg
        if (!$flag) {
            $or = "";
        } else {
            $or = "OR";
        }
        $sql.=" $or desg like '%" . $desg . "%'";
        $flag = TRUE;
    }
    if (isset($cities) && $cities != "") { // condition for cities
        if (!$flag) {
            $or = "";
        } else {
            $or = "OR";
        }
        $sql.=" $or desg like '%" . $cities . "%'";
        $flag = TRUE;
    }
    if (isset($exp) && $exp != "") {// condition for exp
        if (!$flag) {
            $or = "";
        } else {
            $or = "OR";
        }
        $sql.=" $or desg like '%" . $exp . "%'";
        $flag = TRUE;
    }
    if (isset($prof) && $prof != "") {// condition for prof
        if (!$flag) {
            $or = "";
        } else {
            $or = "OR";
        }
        $sql.=" $or desg like '%" . $prof . "%'";
        $flag = TRUE;
    }
    $q = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adjob";
    $q = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

Comment: yes !! it will aslo  work if user select only two input or one input

Comment: But when i m putting two or three inputs it's showing error .. :(

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`  i m getting this error here  `<?php while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) { ?>`

Comment: Should i echo it's data or just echo $sql; ??

Comment: just echo  $sql before mysqli_query!!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM adjob` -  The output

Comment: And echo $sql after two input!!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM adjob` same

Comment: You are doing something wrong because my basic sql is `$sql = "SELECT * FROM adjob WHERE ";` and you not even get `WHERE`. i think your code enter into else condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114730/discussion-between-pooojaaaa-and-saty).

Comment: what i should i do then ?

Comment: yes .. No warnings.. But if m pressing the find button two times it shows the warning.. I should put `e_all e_notice` ..

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work for you

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$desg    = isset($_POST['desg']) ? $_POST['desg'] : '';
$cities  = isset($_POST['cities']) ? $_POST['cities'] : '';
$exp     = isset($_POST['exp']) ? $_POST['exp'] : ''; 
$prof    = isset($_POST['prof']) ? $_POST['prof'] : '';
$sql     = "SELECT * FROM adjob WHERE desg like '%".$desg."%' OR desg like '%".$desg."' OR desg like '".$desg."%' OR cities like '%".$cities."%' OR cities like'".$cities."%' OR cities like '%".$cities."' OR exp like '%".$exp."%' OR exp like '".$exp."%'  OR exp like '%".$exp."' OR prof like '%".$prof."%'";
$q=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
else
{
$sql="SELECT * FROM adjob";
$q=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
?>
<form method="post">
<table width="200" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Desgination</td>
<td><input type="text" name="desg" value="" /></td>
<td>City</td>
<td><input type="text" name="cities" value="" /></td>
<td>Experince</td>
<td><input type="text" name="exp" value="" /></td>
<td>Profile</td>
<td><input type="text" name="prof" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Desg</td>
<td>Cities</td>
<td>Exp</td>
<td>Prof</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $res['desg']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['cities']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['exp']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['prof']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```